# Expo AuthSession immediately resolves as "dismiss"ed

Tags: react-native, expo, auth0

I'm using Expo's [AuthSession](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/) module to sign into Auth0:

```
    let result = await AuthSession.startAsync({
      authUrl: `${auth0Domain}/authorize?` + qs.stringify({
        client_id: auth0ClientId,
        response_type: 'code',
        scope: 'openid profile email offline_access',
        redirect_uri: redirectUrl,
        code_challenge_method: 'S256',
        code_verifier: codeVerifier,
        state: oAuthState,
        audience: auth0Audience
      })
    })

    if (result.type === 'success') {
      ...
    } else if (
      result.type === 'dismiss' ||
      (result.type === 'error' && result.errorCode === 'login-declined')
    ) {
      // FIXME: alert never pops without delay here, despite the if correctly evaluating true
      // Any way to check if the window has closed, if that's the issue?
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))

      let retry = await alertAsync(
        'Authentication dismissed',
        'Cancel signing in?',
        'Try again',
        'Exit'
      )
      return retry ? this.loginWithAuth0() : false
    }
    logger.error('Login failed', result)
    throw new Error('Error signing in')
  }
```

In a dev environment I never have an issue, but in a published app the promise often resolves immediately with `{ type: dismiss }`, **before** the browser closes. Once I caught a glimpse of an alert *(that I try to popup in case the session is actually dismissed)* even before the AuthSession window opened.

If I add a 5s delay before popping the error up, it does show up 5s after starting the `AuthSession` rather than it finishing.

Testing on Android.

I looked into migration over to WebBrowser but it seems to be the same implementation.

Is there a consistent way to actually `await` the Auth process finishing, or should I ditch this whole thing and write my own login screen?

Thanks in advance for any input / direction!

Comment: I can only confirm that we are seeing same problem. Did you tried to open Expo issue on GitHub?

Comment: Not yet, I'm trying to learn more about the issue so that I can make a small demo that could reproduce it. Today I confirmed it doesn't matter which sign in provider is used, but haven't gotten any clues as to what causes it.

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/52a1e3b61343c7cf9589ec7288e5761d0137e606/packages/expo-web-browser/src/WebBrowser.ts#L138 Feel like this here could be the issue but I'll have to play with it later unless someone has dealt with this before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've put a detailed explanation of the problem and a possible solution https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6679#issuecomment-570963717

As a temporary workaround, you can call AppState.currentState somewhere in your app, maybe logging it just to add the right listeners before the user clicks and enable the AuthSession (read more in the linked GitHub issue).

Have a look and comment please :)

Comment: I can confirm that reading `AppState.currentState` before works, thank you! It doesn't seem to work if I call that just before using AuthSession - don't see a reason why, but if I call it in the screen or even App.js the workaround works.

Comment: Yeah that could be because it needs enough time to grab information from the bridge, and it’s scheduled in a UI Thread callback, so it might take a cycle or more to trigger. There’s a better patch for the original code that which I wrote seems to work, we just need to publish it on Expo, stay tuned

Comment: Hello, could you please provide a little code snippet, on how this AppState.currentState works? How do you call it in App.js or before the AuthSession?