# Expo AuthSession does not work on the first try

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-auth-session

I am using [expo-auth-session](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/#providers) to create login screen with Facebook and Google. The issue is `gglResponse` (full code snippet below) is `null` on the first try. If I call the `gglPromptAsync()` again the second time, it would resolve to `success`, assuming the user is able to authenticate themselves with the provider.

I had tried `console.log(AppState.currentState)` on different screens before `gglPromptAsync()` as it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59589158/expo-authsession-immediately-resolves-as-dismissed).

I had tried adding `useProxy: true` and `showInRecents: true` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70286836/how-to-fix-google-expo-auth-session-sign-in-error-something-went-wrong-when-try) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmZm_jPvWWM)

It's quite disappointing that someone has proposed a [solution](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6679#issuecomment-570963717) more than 3 years ago and the behavior is still here.

Here is the code snippet with Google. Facebook is exactly the same.

```js
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';

const [gglRequest, gglResponse, gglPromptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
  expoClientId: mobileSettings.expoClientId,
  iosClientId: mobileSettings.iosClientId,
  androidClientId: mobileSettings.AndroidClientId
});

const onSignInPressed = async (ssoType: SSOType) => {
  await gglPromptAsync({ showInRecents: true, useProxy: true });

  if (gglResponse?.type === 'success') { // gglResponse is null on the first request
    const { authentication } = gglResponse;
    await login(ssoType, authentication?.accessToken || "");
  } else { return; }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those who are having this same issue, you can try using the `response` in the `promptAsync` call, instead of the `gglResponse`. Something like this, and it's working well for me.

```js
gglPromptAsync({ showInRecents: true }).then(async (response) => {
  if (response?.type === "success") {
    const { authentication } = response;
    await login(ssoType, authentication?.accessToken || "").then(() => {
      // other signin logic goes here...
     });
   } else {
     return;
   }
 });
```